# How to set a relative height of a div with no height

Tags: html, css

I need help setting 'div1' to 50% of its parent element: 'div2'. The height of 'div2' is decided by an image inside it. How can I set 'div1' to 50% 'div2'

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/k39048eh/

For 'div1' I have tried: `height: 50%`, `min-height: 50%`;
For 'div2' I have tried: `height: auto`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/k39048eh/7/)**

```
.div2 {
    border: 3px solid blue;
    width: 40%;
    float: right;  
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom:50%;
}
.parent {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="div1">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" class="image" />
        <div class="div2">Needs to be 50% height of DIV1</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's the way to go! Easiest, most solid and readable solution, I've seen so far... was too slow with my edit ;)   [Updated version of OPs fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k39048eh/9/)

Comment: Works a treat! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You could use JQuery but here is my pure CSS way using the table method.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="column"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" class="image"/></div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="row right-side">Upper half</div>

    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
    margin 0;
    padding 0;
}
.container {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 3px solid red;
}
img {
    width: 100%;
    padding 0;
    margin 0;
    border: none;
}
.column {
    width: 50%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
    border: 3px solid green;
}
.row {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    vertical-align: top;    
    display:table;
}
.right-side {
    height:50%;
    display:inline-table;
    border: 3px solid blue;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7y9eK/26/

Comment: it is breaking when some content added below `right-side` div

Comment: No, it doesnt. Have a look at this. You were probably not containing it. http://jsfiddle.net/7y9eK/27/

Answer (score 1):

Use jquery for this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
        var div1=$( '.div1' ).height();
        $('.div2').height(div1/2);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I would prefer an all css answer.

Answer (score 1):

The height of an element can have 5 possible properties [1](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_height.asp):

1. `auto` - The calculated height for this element by the browser.
2. *length* - An explicit length like `200px`, `2em`, or even `0`
3. *percent* - As a percent of its containing block element
4. `inherit` - From its parent
5. `initial` - the default value - `auto` here

The reason your CSS isn't working is because when you tell `.div1` to have a percent-based height, it tries to calculate that value based on a value set for its parent. And since `.div2` has a height of `auto` (by default), and not a specific length based height, `.div1` also defaults to a height of `auto`.

You have a couple options in this scenario:

#### Option 1

Give `.div2` a fixed height in pixels or ems. For example, if you set `height: 200px;`

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vyder/k39048eh/3/

#### Option 2

Give `.div2` a percent height based on its parents (which are html, and body in my example here).

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vyder/k39048eh/2

#### Option 3

However, that's not an ideal solution since you're trying to match `.div2`'s height to fit the image child element's height.

Perhaps, you can set a fixed height for `.div2`, and resize the image to have the same height to give the same effect like this.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vyder/k39048eh/5/

#### Option 4

Finally, when you set an element's position to be `absolute`, the browser follows different rules when drawing it out.

So here I've set `.div1`'s position to be `absolute`, and `.div2`'s to `relative`, so that `.div1`'s dimensions and position are calculated relative to `.div2`'s.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vyder/k39048eh/8/

The problem you face here though is that if `.div1`'s content increases, and its height exceeds that of its parent, `.div2` won't automatically increases its height to fit `.div1`.

---

Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: Very helpful, and I'm sure it would work, but I can only award one answer!

Answer (score -1):

You can do it using CSS calc function:

See: `jsfiddle.net/k39048eh/4/`

The CSS3 calc() function is primarily used to calculate lengths, numbers, angles, transition/animation times or sound frequencies. However, it allows you to mix measurement types — a powerful concept in CSS.

Comment: Please heed the advice of the "links to jsfiddle must be accompanied by code", rather than simply marking the link itself as code.